# Content is hiding while using negative margin

Tags: css

I am using a negative margin for a label and it is not showing.
I have to place a search box on the blue background. If I use a negative margin the box is not showing on the blue background.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

My code is:

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="bg">
 <div class="col-lg-8">
 <h5> Title</h5>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
</div><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
<div id="ParentCaseList_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
<label>Search:<input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
placeholder="" aria-controls="ParentCaseList"></label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .bg{
   border-color: #428bca;
   }
  #ParentCaseList_filter {
  margin-top: -43px;
  }
  div.dataTables_filter {
  text-align: right;
  }
  .dataTables_filter label {
  display: inline-flex !important;
  margin-top: 0rem !important;
  }
  div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_filter label {
  font-weight: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
  }
```

Comment: Dont use negative margin, if you're trying to push any element to top use position

Comment: I have added shared some code. Plz give some solution

Comment: Your code is already moving the search box `43px` upwards...

Comment: @swetha see updated answer down below.

Answer (score 1):

In order to really understand your problem, we'd need more code. We'll need the affected HTML code as well as any other relevant CSS that might have to do with your issue.

Anyhow, there's a *"hack"* to this with the use of the CSS property `z-index`.

Try the following (assuming your margin gives you the desired location for your element):

`{margin-top:-43px; z-index: 999999 !important;}`

The following works fine for me:

```
<style>
    .bg .col-lg-8{
        border-color: #428bca;
        background-color: #428bca;
    }
    #ParentCaseList_filter {
        margin-left: -0%;
        margin-top: -7.93%;
    }
    div.dataTables_filter {
        text-align: right;
    }
    .dataTables_filter label {
        display: inline-flex !important;
        margin-top: 0rem !important;
    }
    div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_filter label {
        font-weight: normal;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
<div class="row">
    <div class="bg">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <h5> Title</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <div id="ParentCaseList_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
            <label>Search:<input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="ParentCaseList"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You must have something else that causes some conflicts somewhere.

I altered the code a bit, but it doesn't affect much. It was basically just for personal testing purposes.

Anyhow, I wasn't able to reproduce your issue with the code provided in your question. I didn't even need the *z-index* hack that I described earlier.

Comment: I have added some code from my project. Kindly tell some solutions

Comment: Have you tried applying the `z-index` property as suggested? It might not be the most *clean* solution, but it should be more than sufficient as the root to the problem could lie within the CSS framework and the use of flexbox in correlation to that.

Comment: Try put an important tag: `{margin-top:-43px; z-index: 999999 !important;}`

Comment: That's more than odd, because it honestly should. Are you sure you are targeting the correct element?

Comment: I'll get back to it.